Pytest in vscode with aws lambda module
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to integrate pytest (via vscode testing tab) with my python lambda project. I know there are tons of similar python layout questions, however none of them quite solve my particular use case, though I don't think what I'm trying to achieve is all that strange. The major requirements are:

Deployable to lambda (I use terragrunt/terraform, specifically this module, though I don't think it's super relevant. It ultimately just zips up the directory you give it, and uploads it to lambda)
A separate test directory that DOES NOT get uploaded to lamba (since there are strict size limitations with lambda, and it's just good policy to keep things small)
I can run the tests in vsCode (currently using pytest through the vsCode Testing tab).

My directory structure looks like this (simplified):
.
├── lambda.tf
├── main.tf
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lambda_handler.py
│   ├── file1.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── subdir
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── file2.py
│   │   ├── file3.py
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── test1.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── subdir
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test2.py
│   │   └── test3.py

The src directory is the one that gets zipped up and uploaded to the lambda, and it is configured to run a method in lambda_handler.py. The test directory might have it's own, distinct requirements.txt, and does not get uploaded to lambda.
lambda_handler.py has the following import statement:
from file1 import <method>
file1.py has the following import statements:
from subdir import file1
from subdir.file2 import <method>
test1.py has the following import statement:
from src import file1
test2.py has the following import statement:
from src.subdir import file2
I also have the following setting.json for vscode. This gets linting working, and makes it possible to run tests.
{
  "jira-plugin.workingProject": "",
  "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
    "."
  ],
  "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
  "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
  "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/src:${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/test",
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/src:${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/test",
  },
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/src:${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/test",
  },
  "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
  "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/modules/invoices/test",
}

With the structure above, I can deploy to lambda and everything works as expected in the cloud. However, I get errors like the below when pytest via vscode does it's test discovery (modified to match simplified dir structure above):
_______________ ERROR collecting test/test1.py ________________
ImportError while importing test module '<redacted>test/test1.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.11.5/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test/test1.py:3: in <module>
    from src import file1
src/file1.py:1: in <module>
    from subdir.file2 import <method>
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subdir'

I can get the test discovery (and then testing itself) to work if I change import statements to use relative paths from .subdir.file2 import  from ..subdir import file1 and the like, but then once I upload it, everything in the lambda fails with errors like the following:
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_handler': attempted relative import with no known parent package
I haven't figured out how to get both to work. I'm also not sure I need the init.py files; I added them because they get mentioned a lot in answers to similar questions, but they don't seem to have made any difference. I'd like to remove them if they're not helping the situation. Is there another setting for pystest that I'm missing? Or is there a different project layout that would work better?

Vscode uses the workspace as the default running folder, so you need to change it to from src.subdir.file2 import <method>.
You could also check this option Execute In File Dir in your settings.

This option allow you to run your scripts in the folder where it is.

Assuming you mean "change the imports within file1 and file2 to start from 'src'", this will indeed make the vscode test work, however then this fails when the lambda is executed: ""errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_handler': No module named 'src'""

Checking the "Execute in file Dir" doesn't seem to change anything

If you add "python.testing.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/src" to your settings.json, will it work?

Nope, seems to make no difference.

I'm open to using a different testing paradigm/tool, or a different project structure. Anything that meets my requirements above. Any recommendations?

Can you try to add the .env file to your workspace folder? Add the PYTHONPATH in this file and "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env", to your settings.json. This may let pytest find your folder.
